# Kindness and mercy from the Ksones Passim

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla

Some people have a custom to say at the end of Birkas Kohanim on Yom Tov the Yehi Ratzon. You can find this prayer [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz%2C_Musaf%2C_First_Day_of_Rosh_Hashana%2C_Avodah.32?vhe=The_Metsudah_Machzor._Metsudah_Publications,_New_York_--_he_(paragraph_ed.)&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):   In this prayer, we say:
כשם שנתת את יוסף צדיקך בשעה שהלבישו אביו כתנת פסים לחן ולחסד ולרחמים בעיניך ובעיני כל רואיו
Just as You gave Joseph, Your righteous one, favor and kindness and mercy in Your eyes and in the eyes of all who saw him when his father dressed him in a colorful coat.

We are asking Hashem to bless us like He blessed Yosef. But where do we learn that Yosef’s colorful coat made him favored, kind and merciful? Is there any source for this idea in the Talmud, the Midrash or Rishonim?

And who composed this Yehi Ratzon in the first place?

Comment: https://torah.org/torah-portion/shabbos-5769-miketz/?print-posts=print

Comment: During the Birkas Kohanim, the Priestly Blessing, we recite a prayer of Y ehi Ratzon where among several requests we appeal to G-d that He endow us with ,חןa special favor in the eyes of G-d and men, ‘just as Y ou granted Y osef, Y our righteous one, at the time his father garbed him in the Kesones Pasim’. The Chasam Sofer teaches that accompanying this gift of a garment was the transmission and understanding of one of the names of G-d, ,פספס"יםwhich imbues a person with a Divine grace so that he be perceived properly with love and favor insuring healthy and honest interactions with others.

Comment: Last comment is from. https://images.shulcloud.com/136/uploads/Bulletins/bulletin409.pdf

Comment: @Chatzkel, Thank you, interesting, but not relevant to the questions. Unless you put the chasam sofer, Rabbi Tiechman and Rabbi Adler as Rishonim, which i don't think is the case.
They are quoting the tefillah, I want to know who the Tefillah is quoting

Comment: In the Siddur vilna they bring that this Yehi Ratzon is from sefer shaare Zion. The Rishonim, and a whole slew of them are mentioned there, said ribbono shel olam three times like the Talmud says. So you’ll be hard pressed to find a rishon discuss this. Regardless, that’s why I made it a comment